# Cannot drag element using JQuery draggable (plus JQuery Collision library)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-collision

I am trying to make a drag-and-drop software using jQuery draggable and jQuery collision extension.

I have two obstacles [in Red] where I can not drag any element. The problem is I can not drag any element even when there are no obstacles.

Here is my problem https://jsfiddle.net/ayank007/gqd3z0cp/28/
In this example, I am assuming 1 foot = 13.75px, which is also the grid size.

```
$(".obj3").draggable({
  grid: [13.75,13.75],
  snap: true,
  snapTolerance: 0,
  obstacle: ".butNotHere",
  preventCollision: true,
  containment: "parent"
})
```

Even without the Grid and Snapping, it's not possible to drag the element.

I want to drag the green div in between the obstacles (red). And even though there is space to drag, I can not drag the green div in between the red ones.

Comment: Your fiddle has two older versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. I was unable to replicate the issue as you described it.

Comment: Actually I'm using jQuery collision library and also a screenshot library [not here] which can only run in particular versions,
In the fiddle try to drag the green div and drop in between the red div's. Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is because of your fractional widths of the red divs. If you make one 302px and the other 303px it works, if you make them both 302.5px it does not. This may well be a limitation of the collision library you are using

Comment: @LeeTaylor thanks Lee, that's must be the issue, can you suggest a better collision detection library/technic

Comment: @Ayan No problem. You have 3 options. 1) Remove fractional dimensions. 2) Find the source code of the collision library and fix it. 3) Find an alternative.